# Can it be possible to make "SourceData:= _" variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below came from a registered macro for creating a pivot table, my wich is to this code available for next row that will be present in the sheet "DONNEES", columns will not increment only, 
It's look like I can set it like "DONNEES!R1C1:R65500C16" but can it be more proper, with a variable that I can include,

```
`ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "DONNEES!R1C1:R1553C16", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion10`
```

Thank's in advance,
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rng as Range

Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DONNEES").Range("A1:P1553")

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= rng, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding what "`_`" does.  In VB "`_`" means the line of code is continued on the line below.  The is the same statement with them removed:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="DONNEES!R1C1:R1553C16", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

Also when you see something like "`SourceType:=`" this is VB's way of allowing non-strict parameter order, where normally a function has its parameters in a specific order and you must pass them in this order, but the "`X:=Y`" layout allows you to tell VB "this parameter value of Y belongs to parameter named X".  Order disregarded.  `SourceType:="DONNEES!R1C1:R1553C16"`  really just says the parameter named "`SourceType`" will receive the value `"DONNEES!R1C1:R1553C16"`

And yes, you could use a variable in the value's place

```
MyVariable="DONNEES!R1C1:R1553C16"
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=MyVariable, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion10
```

However you cannot dynamically change the SourceType:= piece.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit late in time, but I stumbled with a similar problem and maybe my solution is helpful for others.

First, microsoft's documentation says:

> "When passing a Range, it is recommended to either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly."

So in my experience, passing a range object works OK most of the times, but sometimes a type mismatch is returned. The "unexpectedly" ending is what made me go for a workaround, which is very simple. I found that the method will accept rng.Address only if the activesheet is the data sheet, so I do:

```
rng.Worksheet.Activate()
cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches().Create(1, rng.Address, 6)
pivot = cache.CreatePivotTable(destination, name, True, 6)
```

Please, note that I'm doing this in python by using pywintypes, so in VBA would probably be ".Activate" without parentheses, and object variables declared and set, etc.

"destination" in the CreatePivotTable method is a range object and didn't have any problem so far.