# How to create a pivot table for it to change from week to week?

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in an excel spreadsheet and I am trying to create a pivot table of the data where it is able to change from week to week as the data will change. Right now my code works but it is constant where it says “GL ENTERED INV raw data!R3C1:R30C06” how do I get this to change from week to week?

```
Sub ptable 
    Range(“A4:F” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    Sheets.Add
       ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDataBase, SourceData:=“GL ENTERED INV raw data!R3C1:R30C06”, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=“Sheet1!R3C1”, TableName:=“PivotTable1”, DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
End sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can it be possible to make "SourceData:= \_" variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006692/can-it-be-possible-to-make-sourcedata-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a variable holding the last row of your data and replace the "R30" with R & LastRow like this:

```
Sub ptable()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GL ENTERED INV raw data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) 'the 1 means column "A" so if your data has the max rows on column A is ok, otherwise change that number
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="GL ENTERED INV raw data!R3C1:R" & LastRow & "C6", _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=“Sheet1!R3C1”, _
        TableName:=“PivotTable1”, DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12

End Sub
```

You could also just create a `NamedRange`under the ribbon Formulas and use the  `Offset` formula to get a dynamic range, your pivot table would always use as source that `NamedRange`

Comment: I’m the middle part where declaring the source data is, it is giving me an error stating “this command requires at least two rows of source data.” How do I fix this error?

Comment: This is saying that you only got one row of Data. I believe `LastRow` must equal to 3 so if your column A is empty of data, change the 1 when giving the value to the `LastRow` variable for the number of the column which has data.

Comment: How do you change it so that it finds the LastRow starting from the top rather than starting from the bottom as I have inserted rows and I am trying to do the Pivot table of everything above that inserted row?

Comment: `LastRow = .Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown).Row` this would give you the last row from row 3 and column A, so A3 to to the last row(until next blank cell)